# Is there any way to save the progress of detectron2 model training at each iteration?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Is there a way to save the progress of detectron2 model training at each iteration so that I can resume the training process from where it was interrupted?

I have tried, but it gives an assertion error each time progress is about to be saved.

Original Code: [Layout Parser based on detectron2](https://github.com/Layout-Parser/layout-model-training/blob/master/tools/train_net.py)

I have modified the class Trainer(DefaultTrainer) on above script as below but was not successful

```
class Trainer(DefaultTrainer):
    """
    We use the "DefaultTrainer" which contains pre-defined default logic for
    standard training workflow. They may not work for you, especially if you
    are working on a new research project. In that case you can use the cleaner
    "SimpleTrainer", or write your own training loop. You can use
    "tools/plain_train_net.py" as an example.

    Adapted from:
        https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/master/projects/DeepLab/train_net.py
    """

    @classmethod
    def build_train_loader(cls, cfg):
        mapper = DatasetMapper(cfg, is_train=True, augmentations=get_augs(cfg))
        return build_detection_train_loader(cfg, mapper=mapper)

    @classmethod
    def build_evaluator(cls, cfg, dataset_name, output_folder=None):
        """
        Returns:
            DatasetEvaluator or None

        It is not implemented by default.
        """
        return COCOEvaluator(dataset_name, cfg, True, output_folder)

    @classmethod
    def test_with_TTA(cls, cfg, model):
        logger = logging.getLogger("detectron2.trainer")
        # In the end of training, run an evaluation with TTA
        # Only support some R-CNN models.
        logger.info("Running inference with test-time augmentation ...")
        model = GeneralizedRCNNWithTTA(cfg, model)
        evaluators = [
            cls.build_evaluator(
                cfg, name, output_folder=os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, "inference_TTA")
            )
            for name in cfg.DATASETS.TEST
        ]
        res = cls.test(cfg, model, evaluators)
        res = OrderedDict({k + "_TTA": v for k, v in res.items()})
        return res

    @classmethod
    def eval_and_save(cls, cfg, model):
        evaluators = [
            cls.build_evaluator(
                cfg, name, output_folder=os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, "inference")
            )
            for name in cfg.DATASETS.TEST
        ]
        res = cls.test(cfg, model, evaluators)
        pd.DataFrame(res).to_csv(os.path.join(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR, "eval.csv"))
        return res
    
    @classmethod
    def save_model(cls, trainer):
        trainer.checkpointer.save(f"{trainer.cfg.OUTPUT_DIR}/model_{trainer.iter}")
        return None

    def run_step(self):
        loss_dict = super().run_step()
        Trainer.save_model(self)
        return loss_dict
```

error that i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_net.py", line 236, in <module>
    launch(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/detectron2/engine/launch.py", line 62, in launch
    main_func(*args)
  File "train_net.py", line 204, in main
    return trainer.train()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/detectron2/engine/defaults.py", line 431, in train
    super().train(self.start_iter, self.max_iter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/detectron2/engine/train_loop.py", line 138, in train
    self.run_step()
  File "train_net.py", line 124, in run_step
    Trainer.save_model(self)
  File "train_net.py", line 119, in save_model
    trainer.checkpointer.save(f"{trainer.cfg.OUTPUT_DIR}/model_{trainer.iter}")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fvcore/common/checkpoint.py", line 111, in save
    assert os.path.basename(save_file) == basename, basename
AssertionError: /content/layout-model-training/outputs/bib/fast_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/model_0.pth
```

Comment: What is the error? can you add it to the question? it is not entirely clear what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added the error to the question. However, I am not sure if the process I was using was the correct way to save the training progress. If you have any other alternatives, please let me know.